# Application failed codesign verification only when validate built product is set to yes

Tags: ios, verification, codesign

An "In App Purchase" problem made me overanalyze things and got over this bump which I spent 4 hours trying to solve to no avail. I am using Xcode 4.0 with Ios 4.3 SDK. Here it is:

Trying to test my app on the phone, I build it with a provisioning profile with development certificate.The App runs fine on the phone and I get no warnings.However, if I switch on the "validate built product" option in the target build settings, I get this:

*** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

The App still runs just fine on the phone...

If I build the same project with a provisioning profile with distribution certificate, I do not get this warning even if the "validate built product" is switched on.

I tried almost everything until it stroke me like the lightning: is it possible that this warning is a false alarm which says nothing but the obvious that "...it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate"? After all, I know that it is not signed with a submission certificate because I want to test it on my device and I cannot do that if I use a submission certificate...

Can you guys please check this for me on your perfectly working projects? (that is turn on the "validate built product" option then build using a development certificate and see if you get this warning too)

Thank you very much!

Best regards,
Florin

Answer (score 5):

I've been struggling with the exact same warning in a project after updating to Xcode 4.0.
For some reason, the "Validate Built Product" was set to YES in my Developer configuration after moving to Xcode 4. Though only in the "Target -> Build settings", not in the "Project -> Build settings". Setting it to NO fixes the warning in question.

And to answer your question, this makes perfectly sense because the Developer certificate used to sign a build meant to run on your device or simulator, is not an Apple submission certificate.

regards

Comment: Thak you for your answer.Yes, I suppose it makes some sense but I didn't see it at that time...  In case you are not sure of it, please note the documentation states that target build settings always supersede project build settings.